# Swift Combine alternative to Rx Observable.create

Tags: swift, combine

I have some code that is built using RxSwift, and I'm playing around with converting it to use Apple's Combine framework.

One pattern which is very common is the use of `Observable.create` for one-shot observables (usually network requests). Something like this:

```
func loadWidgets() -> Observable<[Widget]> {
  return Observable.create { observer in
    // start the request when someone subscribes
    let loadTask = WidgetLoader.request("allWidgets", completion: { widgets in
      // publish result on success
      observer.onNext(widgets)
      observer.onComplete()
    }, error: { error in
      // publish error on failure
      observer.onError()
    })
    // allow cancellation
    return Disposable {
      loadTask.cancel()
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to map that across to Combine and I haven't been able to quite figure it out. The closest I've been able to get is using Future for something like this:

```
func loadWidgets() -> AnyPublisher<[Widget], Error> {
  return Future<[Widget], Error> { resolve in
    // start the request when someone subscribes
    let loadTask = WidgetLoader.request("allWidgets", completion: { widgets in
      // publish result on success
      resolve(.success(widgets))
    }, error: { error in
      // publish error on failure
      resolve(.failure(error))
    })
    // allow cancellation ???
  }
}
```

As you can see, it does most of it, but there's no ability to cancel.
Secondarily, future doesn't allow multiple results.

Is there any way to do something like the Rx `Observable.create` pattern which allows cancellation and optionally multiple results?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think I found a way to mimic `Observable.create` using a `PassthroughSubject` in `Combine`. Here is the helper I made:

```swift
struct AnyObserver<Output, Failure: Error> {
    let onNext: ((Output) -> Void)
    let onError: ((Failure) -> Void)
    let onComplete: (() -> Void)
}

struct Disposable {
    let dispose: () -> Void
}

extension AnyPublisher {
    static func create(subscribe: @escaping (AnyObserver<Output, Failure>) -> Disposable) -> Self {
        let subject = PassthroughSubject<Output, Failure>()
        var disposable: Disposable?
        return subject
            .handleEvents(receiveSubscription: { subscription in
                disposable = subscribe(AnyObserver(
                    onNext: { output in subject.send(output) },
                    onError: { failure in subject.send(completion: .failure(failure)) },
                    onComplete: { subject.send(completion: .finished) }
                ))
            }, receiveCancel: { disposable?.dispose() })
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

And here is how it looks in usage:

```swift
func loadWidgets() -> AnyPublisher<[Widget], Error> {
    AnyPublisher.create { observer in
        let loadTask = WidgetLoader.request("allWidgets", completion: { widgets in
          observer.onNext(widgets)
          observer.onComplete()
        }, error: { error in
          observer.onError(error)
        })
        return Disposable {
          loadTask.cancel()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer and inspiration.  See my pure Combine implementation below.

Comment: This is a good start, but each subscription should get its own subject so that the closure is called separately for each. Wrapping the return in a `Deferred` will solve that bug. Also, this solution emits values *before* the downstream makes a demand. It should wait until then.

Answer (score 2):

From what I've learned, the support for initializing an `AnyPublisher` with a closure has been dropped in Xcode 11 beta 3. This would be a corresponding solution for Rx's `Observable.create` in this case, but for now I believe that the `Future` is a goto solution if you only need to propagate single value. In other cases I would go for returning a `PassthroughSubject` and propagating multiple values this way, but it will not allow you to start a task when the observation starts and I believe it's far from ideal compared to `Observable.create`.

In terms of cancellation, it does not have an `isDisposed` property similar to a `Disposable`, so it's not possible to directly check the state of it and stop your own tasks from executing. The only way that I can think of right now would be to observe for a `cancel` event, but it's surely not as comfortable as a `Disposable`.
Also, I'd assume that `cancel` might in fact stop tasks like network requests from `URLSession` based on the docs here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/cancellable

Answer (score 1):

Add an isCancelled operation outside the closure and check it in the future's closure. isCancelled can be toggled with the handleEvent() operator.

```
    var isCancelled = false
    func loadWidgets() -> AnyPublisher<[Widget], Error> {
    return HandleEvents<Future<Any, Error>> { resolve in
        // start the request when someone subscribes
        let loadTask = WidgetLoader.request("allWidgets", completion: { widgets in
            // publish result on success
            resolve(.success(widgets))
        }, error: { error in
            // publish error on failure
            resolve(.failure(error))   
        }
        if isCancelled {
            loadTask.cancel()
        }  
        ).handleEvents(receiveCancel: {
        isCancelled = true
        })
    }
}
```

and somewhere in the app you do this to cancel the event

```
loadWidgets().cancel()
```

Also check this [article](https://medium.com/@ahmednasser_43518/integrating-apple-combine-framework-into-an-exciting-ios-project-2a4d770a138c)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that fixes the problems with the accepted solution:

```
extension AnyPublisher {
    struct Subscriber {
        fileprivate let send: (Output) -> Void
        fileprivate let complete: (Subscribers.Completion<Failure>) -> Void

        func send(_ value: Output) { self.send(value) }
        func send(completion: Subscribers.Completion<Failure>) { self.complete(completion) }
    }

    init(queue: DispatchQueue = .main, _ closure: @escaping (Subscriber) -> AnyCancellable) {
        self = Deferred {
            let subject = PassthroughSubject<Output, Failure>()
            var cancellable: AnyCancellable?

            return subject
                .handleEvents(
                    receiveCancel: { cancellable?.cancel() },
                    receiveRequest: { demand in
                        precondition(demand == .unlimited, "AnyPublisher.init only works with unlimited demand")
                        queue.async {
                            cancellable = closure(Subscriber(send: subject.send(_:), complete: subject.send(completion:)))
                        }
                    }
                )
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **ccwasden** for the inspiration.  This replicates Observable.create semantics with a pure Combine implementation without any superfluous entities.

---

### AnyPublisher.create() Swift 5.6 Extension

```
public extension AnyPublisher {
    
    static func create<Output, Failure>(_ subscribe: @escaping (AnySubscriber<Output, Failure>) -> AnyCancellable) -> AnyPublisher<Output, Failure> {
        
        let passthroughSubject = PassthroughSubject<Output, Failure>()
        var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
        
        return passthroughSubject
            .handleEvents(receiveSubscription: { subscription in

                let subscriber = AnySubscriber<Output, Failure> { subscription in

                } receiveValue: { input in
                    passthroughSubject.send(input)
                    return .unlimited
                } receiveCompletion: { completion in
                    passthroughSubject.send(completion: completion)
                }
                
                cancellable = subscribe(subscriber)
                
            }, receiveCompletion: { completion in
                
            }, receiveCancel: {
                cancellable?.cancel()
            })
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        
    }
    
}
```

### Usage

```
func doSomething() -> AnyPublisher<Int, Error> {
    
    return AnyPublisher<Int, Error>.create { subscriber in
        
        // Imperative implementation of doing something can call subscriber as follows
        _ = subscriber.receive(1)
        subscriber.receive(completion: .finished)
        // subscriber.receive(completion: .failure(myError))
        
        return AnyCancellable {
            // Imperative cancellation implementation
        }
    }
    
}
```